# Font rendering some wrong glyphs for Romanian language in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: fonts

Been having this problem since I installed. At first I didn't notice it because I don't visit sites in my native language(Romanian) that often.
Characters would be drawn using the wrong glyphs in chrome, chromium, firefox , thunderbird , libre office etc. for certain fonts. Sad part is these fonts are present often on the web like Arial or Helvetica. This problem never happened in mac os or windows.

- Arial boldens the glyphs for ș ț Ș Ț
- Helvetica replaces the characters completely for î and â
- Liberation Sans has flawless rendering from what I've noticed.

[image: wrong glyph rendering screenshot 2]
[image: wrong glyph rendering screenshot 1]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Would you highlight the correct and wrong on the screenshots. Arial seems the same to me (I don't know the language). Is it just for these two or group of them from different sources? Check font name in "Fonts" tool. Probably, it require reporting upstream project not in Ubuntu.

Comment: AFAIK there is no Arial and Helvetica font in Ubuntu by default. Anyway, can you share a LO Write document containing these characters formatted with the relevant fonts?

Comment: Firefox at least can mess up some characters from fonts from cached pages.  Does the force reload from URL (ctrl-shift-R) fix anything?

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the `font-manager` GUI application to determine whether your fonts support the Romanian characters (`ÂâĂăÎîȘșȚț`). For fonts that do not contain Romanian characters, Romanian characters from other fonts will be substituted.

In my Ubuntu 20.10 installation;

- there is no **Helvetica** font, so it will be substituted by another font (for example, the `fc-match Helvetica` command displays `NimbusSans-Regular.otf: "Nimbus Sans" "Regular"`) and
- the **Arial** font does not support the Romanian characters listed above (again these characters will be substituted by another font).

The fonts that support Romanian characters are these in my case:

***C059, DejaVu Sans, DejaVu Sans Mono, DejaVu Serif, FreeMono, FreeSans, FreeSerif, Liberation Mono, Liberation Sans, Liberation Sans Narrow, Liberation Serif, Nimbus Mono PS, Nimbus Roman, Nimbus Sans, Nimbus Sans Narrow, Noto Mono, P052, Ubuntu, Ubuntu Condensed, Ubuntu Mono, Unifont, URW Bookman, URW Gothic, Z003***.

<sub>I am sharing this information as an answer, because it didn't fit to a comment.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean now. fc-match Helvetica returns Helvetica.ttf: "Helvetica" "Regular" for me. Do I need to manually make assocations for the fonts. How do I do this?   I read I need to make a conf file in /home/caimastraea/.config/fontconfig/conf.d but not sure of the structure

Comment: What is the source of your Helvetica files?  I'd expect modern versions to contain the correct glyphs.  I'd just get rid of that version, since it's probably old or corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be experiencing a font substitution problem. Appropriate fonts are simply not installed. In particular, Georgia is a serif font, but the font shown in the screenshot is sans-serif.

Once installed, appropriate fonts should be substituted in the default font configuration.

- Consider installing the following packages:

  - `fonts-croscore` – Replacements for Arial, Courier, Times (from Google).
  - `fonts-crosextra-caladea` – Replacement for Cambria.
  - `fonts-crosextra-carlito` – Replacement for Calibri.
  - `fonts-liberation` or `fonts-liberation2` – Replacements for Arial, Courier, Times (from Red Hat).
  - `fonts-urw-base35` – Replacements for Arial, Courier, Times, and others (from URW)
- Other packages of interest:

  - `fonts-ibm-plex`
  - `fonts-noto-core` (or `fonts-noto`) – Fonts for multiple languages.
  - `fonts-open-sans`
  - `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` (Microsoft True Type Core Fonts for the Web)
- Fonts to install in `~/.local/share/fonts/`

  - [Gelasio](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Gelasio) – Replacement for Georgia

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed this was the case. Installed font manager also as FedonKadifeli suggested and made substitutions for Georgia and Helvetica. Phew. Glad I don't work as a front-end dev would have pulled my hairs with this stuff :)

Comment: Default `fontconfig` should already have sane substitutions if the packages are installed. My next suggestion if you continued having problems would have been to make custom substitutions. I wasn't aware font manager had that capability.